# Angular ThreeJS | How do I correctly create a custom canvas

Tags: angular, three.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to setup correctly a very basic example with ThreeJS and Angular 8.

When I try to modify the size of my canvas to remove the scrollbars I get the error *"Cannot read property 'width' of null"*.

This is because of the canvas but i don't know why.

**Component.html :**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

**Component.css :**

```
body { 
    margin: 0; 
}

canvas { 
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 100vh; 
    display: block; 
}
```

**Component.ts :**

```
export class Scene3dComponent implements OnInit {

  scene = new THREE.Scene()

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)

  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, canvas: this.canvas})

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startScene();
  }

  startScene() {
    this.renderer.setClearColor('#E5E5E5')
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)

    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / innerHeight
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    })
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding something, but I don't know what.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your posted code that would produce an error "Cannot read property 'width' of null".... but I did see that `this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / innerHeight` should probably be `this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way for implementing threejs in angular.

- So in my advice first you can use ElementRef and @ViewChild  to get a canvas
- Create service which contains your function (Create scene, animate ... )

  ```js
  import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

  /**
   * Engine 3D
   */
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-engine-frame',
    templateUrl: './engine-frame.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./engine-frame.component.css'],
  })
  export class EngineFrameComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('rendererCanvas', {static: true})
    public rendererCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    /**
     * Contructor
     * @param engService
     */
    constructor(private engService: EngineFrameService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.engService.createScene(this.rendererCanvas);
      this.engService.animate();
    }
  }

  /**
  * Engine service
  */
  import * as THREE from 'three';
  import {ElementRef, Inject, Injectable, NgZone, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class EngineFrameService implements OnDestroy {
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
    scene: THREE.Scene;
    frameId: number = null;
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private rendererService: RendererService ) {
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    }
    createScene(canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>): void {
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
      this.canvas = canvas.nativeElement;
      this.renderer = this.rendererService.create(this.canvas); // Create service for renderer
      // create your camera
    }
  public animate(): void {
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
          this.resize();
        });
    }
    public render(): void {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.render();
      });
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }

    public resize(): void {
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          const width = this.canvas.offsetWidth;
          const height = this.canvas.offsetHeight;
          this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        });
    }
  ```

  ```html
  <canvas #rendererCanvas></canvas>
  ```